# Unexpected behavior when reading input parameters from stdin

Tags: c, stdin

I am testing a program "myprog.c" that crashes if it runs with any input parameter:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * arg[]){
  if (argc > 1 ){
    abort();

  }
}
```

As expected, "./myprog.out abc" crashes. But then I tried to get inputs from a file:  "./myprog.out < inputs.txt", where inputs.txt has a couple of  words, the program does not crash. Why not?

Comment: Because `argc` is not greater than 1.

Comment: Your program should crush when it is executed with parameters. `inputs.txt` here is a redirection to standard input, not a parameter to your program.

Comment: @Stargateur There is no need if you program only occasionally.

Comment: Read *something* that would inform you how arguments and input work. Trial and error is no way to learn a language and write decent programs.

Comment: @zell This don't make any sense; Imagine you drive occasionally, with your argument, you don't need to learn to drive ? Please... C is like all other thing in life, learn it if you want use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the shell doesn't pass `< inputs.txt` as arguments. Instead the shell makes it so that the contents of `inputs.txt` is to be read from `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks. Then, what would be the right way to pass the content of inputs.txt as parameters?

Comment: @zell That really depends on the shell you're using. Judging by the way you run your program, I guess you're on a Linux system? And then probably using Bash as the shell? Then you can use e.g. `./myprog.out $(cat inputs.txt)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because argc is equal to 1, you can verifie it with the following code:

```
int     main(int argc, char * arg[])
{
    printf("argc = %i\n", argc);
    if (argc > 1 ) {
        abort();
    }
}
```

output:

> argc = 1

it appear because you can't pass argument like it, if you do it with a < your program will interpret it like it provide from stdin (filedescriptor numero 0)

if you want to pass more argument than 1, do like it:

> ./a.out abc def ghi

if you want get "argument" by a file, use a getline